# What is is $h'(3)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this question from school and it's a little hard to understand. I thought of using the quotient rule but the function is like composition of two other functions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is the quotient of $a(x) = f(x)+4$ and $ b(x) = g(x)+2x$. Work out the formula for $({a \over b})'(3)$.

Comment: The derivative of $h$ at $3$ only depends on the behavior of $h$ near $x=3$, so you only need to be concerned with the formulas for $f$ and $ g$ near $x=3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we apply derivative rules, namely the quotient rule, we note that

$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)(g(x) + 2x) - (f(x) + 4)(g'(x) + 2)}{(g(x)+2x)^2}$$

This holds because the derivative of the numerator of $h$ is $f'(x)$, and the derivative of the denominator of $h$ is $g'(x)+2$. Essentially you can rewrite $h$ as

$$h(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \implies h'(x) = \frac{p'(x)q(x) - p(x)q'(x)}{(q(x))^2}$$

for $p(x) = f(x)+2$ and $q(x) = g(x)+2x$, and apply the rules from there. Just be sure to get back into terms of $f,g$ afterwards!

Now, recall that $f'(x)$ denotes the slope of the line tangent to $f$ at the point $x$. In particular, if $f$ is linear, then it is the slope of the graph at that point. With this in mind, you can easily find $f'(3)$ and $g'(3)$ just from the graphs you have. Then you only need to plug in $x=3$ into the formula above!